# Min and Max from split entry written in Message (PAGE GUI)

Tags: python

I would appreciate an explanation as of why is this code returning value in single numbers for example list gore 12,4,5,7,124, code will return numeral 7 instead of 124

```
list = w.Entry1.get()
list.sort[',']

maxVal = list[0]

for i in range(0, len(list), 1):

    if maxVal < list[i]:
        maxVal = list[i]

RandomMessage = maxVal

w.Message1.config(text=RandomMessage)
```

Comment: If you are using the sort method you don't need to use that for loop to get max value. You can simply get the last value of the list using list[-1]. Also don't name your variable "list". List is a keyword and will cause conflicts. I tried out your code without the tkinter entry and naming the variable lst. It works fine

Comment: Thank you so much, means a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [12, 4, 5, 7, 124]
lst.sort()
maxVal = lst[-1]
print(maxVal)
```

This is a much more simplified version of the code. Try using this with your application.

Comment: Any clarification means a lot, appreciate it thanks !

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need any further explaination. If my answer solves your issue please mark it as correct and upvote. Cheers